# Export iPhoto library onto Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, backup, photos.app, library

I have Time Machine, and am looking to have iphoto continuously and automatically back up my pictures. (I have so many images and would like them safely on a hard drive).
I had to drag/copy my iPhoto library onto Time Machine, and I can open it and view pictures, but they are only the ones that were there at the time, and none of the new images that have been imported since then.

I also know how to switch back and forth from the two iphoto libraries, my default one and the external library, but again same problem - only the older images appear when it's under the library of the external hard drive.

For some reason the iPhoto library which should be under Pictures, is nowhere on my Time Machine. How do I place the iPhoto library back into Time Machine, and have it just automatically back it up so that I don't manually have to do it? (I've tried googling this but can't find a black and white answer).

Comment: You should be able to go to the folder containing your photo library and open Time Machine on that to see old versions.  I am not sure if looking inside the library is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine automatically copies everything on your user folder, so you don't have to manually drag your iPhoto library to your external drive to back it up. Unless of course you have excluded some files or folders on the Time Machine preference pane, in which case no backups of such resources are being made.

In order to see the library on your Time Machine backup, you would have to mount your .sparsebundle and then look for it, and it does not seem to be the case.